# Onsen UI page orientation property for landscape and portrait

Tags: screen-orientation, onsen-ui, landscape-portrait

I am new for Onsen UI. I want to control individual page orientation like one page work only in portrait mode, one another for landscape mode and one for both. Is this possible with Onsen UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a one page being displayed in one orientation and another one in the other then it is possible even though I wouldn't recommend it. Usually using [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to change the styles of the page itself is the preferred method. However if you *must* do it then you can do:

```
<ons-if orientation="landscape">
  <ons-page>Landscape page</ons-page>
</ons-if>

<ons-if orientation="portrait">
  <ons-page>Portrait page</ons-page>
</ons-if>
```

Here are the [docs for `ons-if`](https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons-if.html).

If you're using Onsen 1 then you can use [`ons-if-orientation`](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-if-orientation.html)

**Update:**
The above code does work, but I guess it's not what you want. It seems like what you want is not to display a page if the orientation matches, but rather to force the orientation based on the page if I understand correctly.

If you want to force a specific orientation then I'm sorry to say that Onsen does not provide that functionality currently. [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android)

Cordova provides some features like this
`<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` in the `config.xml` but I think that's for the whole app, not only for a specific page.
It seems that there is a [plugin](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) which is supposed to be able to do it on a per-page basis. There are standards about this still in development if I'm not mistaken, but maybe they're not implemented everywhere.

I guess there is [something](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android) like 
`<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` which you could put in your HTML, where the json contains `{"orientation":  "landscape"}`, but again I'm not sure that this will work everywhere. Maybe it will work only in Android.

One last thing you could do is something like

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
    body { transform: rotate(90deg) }
}
```

however doing a rotation like that is going to probably create more issues and is not recommended.

Probably the `manifest.json` could be a solution for android or just the cordova plugin otherwise.

Comment: It is not working for me. It display page changes in both orientation. I want if this condition apply according to you "<ons-if orientation="landscape">" then page displays in landscape either orientation is landscape or portrait.

Comment: I updated my answer. The original one works, but I guess it just doesn't do what you want. If you want to force the orientation that is most likely going to require something from the cordova side.